# browserify.require does not work with jsx files in from version 9

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I have this little bundle program using the browserify api:

```
var browserify = require('browserify')
var b = browserify()
b.transform('reactify')
b.require('./my-component.jsx')
b.bundle(function (e, val) {
  console.log(e == null)
})
```

This will work in browserify versions < 9 but not above. The problem is the react component and the error looks like this:

```
    <div></div>
    ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Is there any explanation to this? It seems to work from the commande line using: `browserify -r ./my-component.jsx -t reactify` but I would like to use the API.

Comment: Have you looked at this issue? https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify/issues/20

Comment: global: true helped. But I don't understand why